# how to run countdowntimer throughout an application in android?

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I am trying to add countdowntimer in my application, i want to run timer for 5 minutes throughout an application without pause and cancel and as well as restart...I have tried several code but I didn't get desired output!

Problem faced:
   when I'm trying to intent from MainActivity to Main2Activity it works fine but 
   If Main2Activity to MainActivity, timer get's restart!

```
//MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    Button button;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id1);
        new CountDownTimer(300000, 1000) { // adjust the milli seconds here

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                textView.setText(""+String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes( millisUntilFinished),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                textView.setText("done!");
            }
        }.start();
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent in=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
    }
}

//Main2Activity.java

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Button btn2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(Main2Activity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code

Comment: ok..wait for sometime

Comment: i guess you can use application class to create such timer but that timer will be limited to lifecycle of application

Comment: ohk...but how can i access UI (i.e. seconds remaining in text view) in Application class??

Comment: How about a thread that always saves the result to a shared preference.

Comment: @M.Mavini can you please elaborate!

Comment: @NoobDogg here is a code!

Comment: If you want to send data back from Activity2 to Activity1, then why not use StartActivityForResults from Activity1 and in Activity2 use finish()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Main2Activity is starting a new instance of MainActivity. If you want to return to the original MainActivity, use `finish()` instead of `startActivity()`.

Comment: but I have to give an Intent rather than finish();...i dont want to finish my second Activity

Comment: In your manifest, what are the `launchMode`s for the two activities? If you want to go back to the main activity, it should be `singleTop`.

Comment: can you able to tell me which method of an Activity is called once in its one session even if we intent this activity several times!

Comment: Your activity stack will look like this: MainActivity(timer1) -> Main2Activity -> MainActivity(timer2) -> Main2Activity -> MainActivity(timer3)... @acallan is right, you should call `finish()` if you want to go back to your original timer. You could also look into [`onActivityResult`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) if you need the data in your intent for some reason.